# AngularJS - Selectize.Js - trouble in in initialization

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selectize.js

I'm trying to create my own angular directive, which use the js library selectize.js.
It's working fine when i add element in the input, info are populated to the model,
But i have some trouble to initialize the input with the model info.

You can see what i'm trying to do right here : http://plnkr.co/edit/e2IHAQLcfdmuWcjVq1YL

As you can see, the input is empty despite data in myValue.